# Topologically finitely generated residually finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, topological-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a topologically finitely generated profinite group,
and let $H$ be a subgroup of countably infinite index. Is $H$ necessarily topologically finitely generated with the subspace topology inherited from $G$?

Comment: Note that it is no restriction to assume that $H$ is dense (because its closure is necessarily open). On the other hand when $H$ is dense but not assumed of countable index, there are counterexamples, e.g. $\bigoplus_n Alt_n\subset \prod_n Alt_n$.